# Replace letters in a template string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringi

Given a "template" of a UK postcode, such as "A9 9AA", where "A" is a letter placeholder, and "9" is a number placeholder, I want to generate random postcode strings like "H8 4GB".  Letters can be any uppercase letter, and numbers anything from 0 to 9.

So if the template is "AA9A 9AA" then I want strings like "WC1A 9LK". I'm ignoring for now generating "real" postcodes, so I'm not bothered if "WC1A" is a valid outward code.

I've scraped around trying to get functions from the `stringi` package to work, but the problem seems to be that replacing or matching the "A"s in a template will only replace the first replacement, for example:

```
 stri_replace_all_fixed("A9 9AA",c("A","A","A"), c("X","Y","Z"), vectorize_all=FALSE)
[1] "X9 9XX"
```

so it doesn't replace each "A" with each element from the replacement vector (but this is by design).

Maybe there's something in `stringi` or base R that I've missed - I'd like to keep it in those packages so I don't bloat what I'm working on.

The brute-force method is to split the template, do replacements, paste the result back together but I'd like to see if there's a quicker, naturally vectorised solution.

So to summarise:

```
foo("A9 9AA") # return like "B6 5DE"
foo(c("A9 9AA","A9 9AA","A9A 9AA")) # returns c("Y6 5TH","D4 8JH","W0Z 3KQ")
```

Here's a non-vectorised version which relies on constructing an expression and evaluating it...

```
random_pc <- function(fmt){
    cc = gsub(" ",'c(" ")',gsub("9","sample(0:9,1)",gsub("A","sample(LETTERS,1)",strsplit(fmt,"")[[1]])))
    paste(eval(parse(text=paste0("c(",paste(cc,collapse=","),")"))),collapse="")    
}

> random_pc("AA9 9AA")
[1] "KO6 1AY"
```

Comment: I assume it is important that it is an arbitrary template, and that you're not just looking for something to generate a pattern?

Comment: There's a small number of possible formats - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom - but I might also want to generate bad ones for testing.

Comment: And I suspect using `lapply` to iterate over the template counts as a "non-quick,  non-natural vectorised" brute-force method?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, OP wants to randomly create `UK POST CODE` in specified format. I think `sprintf` can help like:

```
sprintf("%s%s %d%d%s", sample(LETTERS,1),sample(LETTERS,1), sample(0:9,1),
                sample(0:9,1), sample(LETTERS,1) )
#1] "BC 59D"
```

Now, if purpose is to provide the format using `9` and `A` then step will be to first replace `9` with `%d` and `A` with `%s`.

**OPTION#2**

Another option can be achieved using `paste0` and `sapply` using a custom function as:

```
fmt <- "AA 9AA A"
paste0(sapply(strsplit(fmt,""), getCodeText), collapse = "")
#"YF 7OP Z"


#custom function to generate random characters
getCodeText <- function(x){
  retVal = x
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    if(x[i] == "A"){
      retVal[i] = sample(LETTERS,1)
    }else if(x[i] == "9"){
      retVal[i] = as.character(sample(0:9,1))
    }
  }
  retVal
}
```

Comment: I've edited my q to show an answer based on constructing and evaluating an expression like your first option.

Comment: @Spacedman That looks good. Actually I was working on something similar for my option#2. Finally realized that `paste0` with custom function can be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution (vectorised the lazy way) that splits the format and then replaces based on character or numeric:

```
randpc <- Vectorize(function(s){
    s = strsplit(s,"")[[1]]
    NUMS = as.character(0:9)
    nLet = sum(s %in% LETTERS)
    nDig = sum(s %in% NUMS)
    s[s %in% LETTERS] = sample(LETTERS, nLet, replace=TRUE)
    s[s %in% NUMS] = sample(NUMS, nDig, replace=TRUE)
    paste0(s, collapse="")
})
```

Has the useful side effect of returning a named vector that shows the format string:

```
> randpc(c("AA9 9AA","A9 9AA"))
  AA9 9AA    A9 9AA 
"QS4 4LW"  "S9 7EU"
```

Its also flexible in that it can create postcodes based on another postcode, since it accepts any letter or number in the format string:

```
> randpc(rep("LA1 4YF",3))
  LA1 4YF   LA1 4YF   LA1 4YF 
"OL2 5OJ" "YK3 3YB" "FV0 1LW"
```

Comment: Good efforts!! I think it will be worth finding efficiency of these different answers.

Comment: This solution is about 10x faster than the `eval`-based one in my Q.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what counts as brute force, since a split-replace-combine workflow on the strings seemed the most intuitive to me. However, my first attempts were pretty slow with very large numbers of templates. I had also hoped something like `stri_replace_all(replacement = sample(LETTERS, 1))` would work but it also only replaces with the same letter.

This is a slightly different approach using `stri_replace_first`, replacing the first instance of a template character until there are no template characters left. This means I switch the template to be lowercase `l` for letters and `n` for numbers, since postcodes are uppercase letters and numbers only (as far as I know). I think the running time is a lot more reasonable (~10 secs) for 100k templates and this also only uses `stringi`.

```r
library(stringi)

make_postcodes <- function(templates){
  postcodes <- templates
  while (any(stri_detect_regex(postcodes, "l|n"))){
    for (i in 1:length(templates)){
      postcodes[i] <- stri_replace_first_fixed(
        str = postcodes[i],
        pattern = "l",
        replacement = sample(LETTERS, 1)
        )
      postcodes[i] <- stri_replace_first_fixed(
        str = postcodes[i],
        pattern = "n",
        replacement = sample(0:9, 1)
        )
    }
  }
  postcodes
}

make_postcodes("ln nll")
#> [1] "W8 3MX"
make_postcodes(c("ln nll", "ln nll", "lnl nll"))
#> [1] "H1 6TN"  "C5 6YI"  "A3I 2DB"

test = stri_trim_both(stri_rand_strings(100000, sample(5:9, 1), pattern = "[nl\\ ]"))
tictoc::tic("Time to convert 100,000 templates")
x <- make_postcodes(test)
tictoc::toc()
#> Time to convert 100,000 templates: 12.03 sec elapsed
head(test)
#> [1] "lnnl"  "ll l"  "nl n"  "ll  l" "ll l"  "ll n"
head(x)
#> [1] "G91U"  "HU N"  "2Q 7"  "EU  Z" "PD I"  "SM 4"
```

Created on 2018-04-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).